# What data type to use for an ordered pairing of items?

Tags: cocoa, core-data, data-structures

I have a bunch of data (**data that will remain constant**) that I want to import in to my Cocoa app (OS X, iOS).  This data is a pairing of "Title" and "Body" where the title might be "Really Cool Stuff" and body will be "Gosh, there's a lot of really cool stuff.  Here's a big list...".  There are several of these pairs, in an **ordered** list.

One data type that comes to mind is to create a aggregate object type with `NSString *title;` and `NSString *body;` properties, and then have an array of these.  Is there another way such as an ordered dictionary.. (where `title` is a unique key in to dictionary of `body`)?

Last piece of the puzzle - I want this data to be in a **persistent data store** of some sort, the more automatic the better.  Ideally, I want to use Core Data.  So an answer that addresses this in terms of Core Data is preferred.  To complicate things, the data is being spit out of a perl script (would be tricky to rewrite in Objective-C/C)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can design it based off of NSString as you alluded to.  You'd then be able to insert the whole object into Core Data at some point in your program.  In your Core Data design, you could just have one block containing the two attributes of the object.

Comment: @Nektarios Well, that depends.  I'd say you could just throw in a quicksort or something and sort the various objects into an array, based off whichever attribute you want to sort with.